# How to display the result if the time difference is more than one hour

Tags: mysql

I want to display the result where if the time difference is more than one hour. Here is the sample query:

```
SELECT 
  locator_id,
  NAME,
  DATE,
  destination,
  time_leave,
  time_return,
  isOfficial 
FROM
  locator_table
```

and this is the result:

```
locator_id  name    date        destination  time_leave  time_return  isOfficial  
----------  ------  ----------  -----------  ----------  -----------  ------------
         1  ALEX    2019-07-31  FRANCE       09:40 AM    09:50 AM                0
         2  MARK    2019-07-30  GERMANY      11:00 AM    01:00 PM                1
         3  JOHN    2019-07-30  TAIWAN       11:15 AM    12:00 PM                1
         4  FOO     2019-07-31  KOREA        01:20 PM    02:30 PM                1
         5  BAR     2019-07-30  JAPAN        01:50 PM    02:00 PM                0
```

Now as you can see `locator_id 2 and 4` are the ones with more than one hour time difference. And this should be the result:

```
locator_id  name    date        destination  time_leave  time_return  isOfficial  
----------  ------  ----------  -----------  ----------  -----------  ------------
         2  MARK    2019-07-30  GERMANY      11:00 AM    01:00 PM                1
         4  FOO     2019-07-31  KOREA        01:20 PM    02:30 PM                1
```

how to achieve this?

Comment: What did you try ? Also what is the type of `time_leave` and `time_return` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use MySQL's [TIMEDIFF](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html) function and it should be something like:

```
select *
from locator_table 
where 
hour(timediff(time_leave, time_return)) >= 1
and 
minute(timediff(time_leave, time_return)) >= 1
```

[Fiddle Demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/6bRHy9k4SLAVotrFfcg9FC/2)

Comment: There is one problem in your answer. When the difference is exactly one hour, it still displays the result. It should only display `> 1 hour`, not `>= 1 hour`.

Comment: Ooops, missed that. Fixed it by taking the hour and minute extraction. So now it checks if the hour is at least 1 as well as the minute is at least 1 minute, so anything >1h or >=1h1m will be shown. :) Updated the fiddle too. Please check.

Answer (score 0):

If the `time_leave` and `time_return` columns are of the TIME or DATETIME type, you could use the MySQL [TIMEDIFF](https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/date-and-time-functions/mysql-timediff-function.php) function to calculate the difference, use the [HOUR](https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/date-and-time-functions/mysql-hour-function.php) function to extract the hours part from the difference and select rows accordingly.

This statement would do the trick:

```
SELECT 
  locator_id,
  NAME,
  DATE,
  destination,
  time_leave,
  time_return,
  isOfficial 
FROM
  locator_table 
WHERE 
  HOUR(TIMEDIFF(time_return, time_leave)) > 1
```

Please be aware that this will only work with DATETIME or TIME typed values.
If the values are VARCHAR or CHAR typed, you'll need to do some conversion to TIME or DATETIME types on beforehand.

Comment: I tested it with VARCHAR and it seems to be working fine too. Am I doing something wrong? Could you please check: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/6bRHy9k4SLAVotrFfcg9FC/0, I used the same format as OP just out of curiosity and it worked fine.

Comment: The cast to the TIME type could be done by mysql automatically, and this works because of the exact content of the field (which conforms to a time representation). When the value of the VARCHAR isn't a valid time or datetime representation, it'll probably fail.

Comment: True that. But since the format is fine, looks fine.